# Populate dates for each outlet

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the link 
[Easiest way to populate a temp table with dates between and including 2 date parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812986/easiest-way-to-populate-a-temp-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-par)

I generated a table

```
Date
2012-01-01
2012-01-02
..
2012-01-31
```

I need to ask how to combine with my outlet table?

Say I have an outlet table

```
ID | Name
1  | Outlet A
2  | Outlet B
3  | Outlet C
```

I want to combine generated dates table and outlet table to be like below, so each date has all of the outlets

```
Date       | Outlet
2012-01-01 | Outlet A
2012-01-01 | Outlet B
2012-01-01 | Outlet C
2012-01-02 | Outlet A
2012-01-02 | Outlet B
2012-01-02 | Outlet C
...
2012-01-31 | Outlet A
2012-01-31 | Outlet B
2012-01-31 | Outlet C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by simple query :

```
select a.date , b.Name
from dates as a , outlets as b
```

it will return result you want . this query will return Cartesian Product of tables which are in from clause . check [article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm) for more detail .

Comment: Thanks, very simple, why did I never think about that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.Date, o.Outlet
FROM DatesTable d
CROSS JOIN OutletsTable o
```

Comment: Great! this also has the right result. Is there any difference with the other answer below?

Comment: @Akhtar It's a syntax difference. Performance and results are the same. Using `CROSS JOIN` is SQL-92 standard, while the other answer is using old style joins - SQL-89 syntax. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins