# how to display dates between two dates using mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi i try to display dates between two dates(i don't have any table ) using mysql.
simply i have two dates 2013-10-01 and 2013-10-05 but i did't success

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(Day,@StartDate) = 1 THEN @StartDate 
            ELSE DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month,0,@StartDate)+1,0) END AS myDate
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(Month,1,myDate)
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(Month,1,myDate) <=  @EndDate
)
SELECT myDate
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[Easiest way to populate a temp table with dates between and including 2 date parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812986/easiest-way-to-populate-a-temp-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-par)

i think this works on only sqlserver not in mysql

i want output like

```
2013-10-01
2013-10-02
2013-10-03
2013-10-04
2013-10-05
```

Comment: The CTE function is not part of MySQL.

Comment: For MySQL have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query