# Expand "From" & "To" date columns to 1 row per day within that range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

Take the following sample data:

```
WITH SampleData AS (
    SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 28.5 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 33 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-04-25 00:00:00.0000' AS StartDate, '2014-04-30 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 36 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 20 AS HPW
)
SELECT * FROM SampleData
```

How can we expand this data as follows (when there is no end date, assume current date):

[image]

I suspect some kind of recursion / CTE / tally table will be required here but cant quite get my head round it!

Comment: Create the generator and join with your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to make a date generator; entire articles have been devoted to which one is fastest, but for simplicity's sake I'm going to tweak the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812986/easiest-way-to-populate-a-temp-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-par). I'd recommend doing some reading on the topic, and persisting a real date table in your database that you can use for queries like this (rather than generate one on the fly for each query you execute).

Step One: create a date table

Step Two: join each date within the table to an employee (note: I'm also filtering this to only show dates greater than the minimum start date in SampleData)

Step Three: join the date / distinct employees to your data to retrieve the HPW in force as of the given date.

SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'; -- this can be any date below the minimum StartDate

WITH SampleData AS (
    SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 28.5 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 33 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-04-25 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2014-04-30 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 36 AS HPW
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 20 AS HPW
),
SampleDateTable AS 
  (
    SELECT @StartDate AS myDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(Day,1,myDate)
    FROM SampleDateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(Day,1,myDate) <=  GETDATE()
)
SELECT 
    EachEmployee.EmployeeID,
    a.myDate,
    SampleData.HPW
FROM 
    SampleDateTable a
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT EmployeeID, MIN(StartDate) MinStartDate
        FROM SampleData
        GROUP BY EmployeeID
      ) EachEmployee ON 
        a.MyDate >= EachEmployee.MinStartDate
     LEFT JOIN 
    SampleData ON
        EachEmployee.EmployeeID = SampleData.EmployeeID AND
        a.myDate >= SampleData.StartDate AND
        a.myDate <= ISNULL(SampleData.EndDate, GETDATE())
ORDER BY EachEmployee.EmployeeID DESC, a.MyDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could simply continue CTE:

```
--Replace the enddate with "Getdate()" if you require expansion until "today/current"
Declare @DefaultEnddate Datetime = '2014-10-15 00:00:00.000'

;WITH SampleData AS (
SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2014-08-31 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 28.5 AS HPW
UNION ALL
SELECT '8000213' AS EmployeeID, '2014-10-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 33 AS HPW
UNION ALL
SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-04-25 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, '2014-04-30 00:00:00.000' AS EndDate, 36 AS HPW
UNION ALL
SELECT '0003289' AS EmployeeID, '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' AS StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, 20 AS HPW
)
, Base as ( SELECT EmployeeID, StartDate = Convert(datetime, StartDate) , EndDate = Convert(datetime,isnull(EndDate,@DefaultEnddate)), HPW FROM SampleData)
, Expanded as (Select EmployeeID, StartDate as [Date], HPW , EndDate from Base
                union all
                Select EmployeeID, [Date] = [Date] + 1, HPW , EndDate from Expanded where [Date] < EndDate
        )
select EmployeeID,[Date], HPW
from Expanded 
Order by EmployeeID, [Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```