# Populating a table with all dates in a given range in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any convenient way to populate a table with all dates in a given range in Google BigQuery? What I need are all dates from 2015-06-01 till CURRENT_DATE(), so something like this:

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-06-01 |
| 2015-06-02 |
| 2015-06-03 |
| ...        |
| 2016-07-11 |
+------------+
```

Optimally, the next step would be to also get all weeks between the two dates, i.e.:

```
+---------+
| week    |
+---------+
| 2015-23 |
| 2015-24 |
| 2015-25 |
| ...     |
| 2016-28 |
+---------+
```

I've been fiddling around with the following answers I found, but I can't get them to work, mostly because core functions aren't supported and I can't find proper ways to replace them.

[Easiest way to populate a temp table with dates between and including 2 date parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812986/easiest-way-to-populate-a-temp-table-with-dates-between-and-including-2-date-par)

[Generate Dates between date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges)

Your help is very much appreciated!

Best,
Max

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> all dates from 2015-06-01 till CURRENT_DATE()

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2015-06-01"), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS DAY
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
     FROM (FLATTEN((
     SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), TIMESTAMP("2015-06-01")), '.'),'') AS h
     FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
)))
```

> all weeks between the two dates

```
SELECT YEAR(DAY) AS y, WEEK(DAY) AS w
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2015-06-01"), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS DAY
  FROM (
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
       FROM (FLATTEN((
       SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), TIMESTAMP("2015-06-01")), '.'),'') AS h
       FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
  )))
)
GROUP BY y, w
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 68):

Mikhail's answer works for BigQuery's legacy sql syntax perfectly.  This solution is a slightly easier one if you're using the standard SQL syntax.

BigQuery standard SQL syntax actually has a built in function, [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array) for creating an array from a date range.  It takes a start date, end date and `INTERVAL`.  For example:

```
SELECT day
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2015-06-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS day
```

If you wanted the week and year you could use

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(WEEK FROM day)
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2015-06-01'), CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
) AS day
```