# BIGQUERY - HOW TO USE SUM FUNCTION BY SPECIFIC DATE?

Tags: google-bigquery

So basically, i want to caculate SUM of EST_VIEWS by DATE which is cumulative between `"2018-09-07" and "2018-09-13"`. How can i do it?

```
Row CMS_ID  VIDEO_ID    CHANNEL_ID  TITLE   EST_VIEWS   DATE     
1   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    1   2018-09-10   
2   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    3   2018-09-07   
3   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    1   2018-09-09   
4   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    3   2018-09-11   
5   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2   2018-09-13   
6   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    1   2018-09-12   
7   2   V133h8Rn8W0 UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Michael Jackson Nhí - Châu Phát Luân Ngôi Sao Nhí Trại Hè Trường Anh Ngữ RES 2018   1   2018-09-11   
8   2   V133h8Rn8W0 UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Michael Jackson Nhí - Châu Phát Luân Ngôi Sao Nhí Trại Hè Trường Anh Ngữ RES 2018   1   2018-09-12
```

The result:

```
Row CMS_ID  VIDEO_ID    CHANNEL_ID  TITLE   DATE    total    
1   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-10  1    
2   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-11  3    
3   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-07  3    
4   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-09  1    
5   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-12  1    
6   2   WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ    Con Két Quậy    2018-09-13  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to see all dates in the given range, even when your source table may not have any entries for those dates, we can use a calendar table in this case.  Given that your desired range is small, the following should suffice:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-07") AS DATE UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-08") UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-09") UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-10") UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-11") UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-12") UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE("2018-09-13")
)

SELECT
    t1.DATE,
    SUM(t2.EST_VIEWS) OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE) AS total
FROM dates t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.DATE = t2.DATE
GROUP BY
    t1.DATE;
```

Note that if you needed a larger range of dates, then you would probably a want a cleaner, more automated way of generating a calendar table.  [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694040/how-to-generate-date-series-to-occupy-absent-dates-in-google-biqquery) for some options.

Comment: I tried your way. But i still didn't get the expected result
`Row CMS_ID VIDEO_ID CHANNEL_ID TITLE DATE total  
1 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-10 1  
2 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-11 3  
3 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-07 3  
4 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-09 1  
5 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-12 1  
6 2 WKqQSws7CRM UC-CcF1XGCRASDRrEOI_zEnQ Con Két Quậy 2018-09-13 2  `

Comment: it is hard to see here, i will put the result on the post

Comment: Do you want to report all dates, even those dates which don't appear in your table?

Comment: yes, i want to report all dates, i mean i want to have a table which is calculated `SUM` EST_VIEWS by each VIDEO_ID (cumulative between '2018-09-07' AND '2018-09-13')

Comment: @PhucTrinh I updated my answer to use a calendar table.

Comment: I tried your way again, but it is still not cumulative :(

Comment: I explain the cumulative in the comment above.

Comment: Please help me, I mentioned about calculating cumulative in the comment, but seems like you dont see it. Now i just edit in the question. Please help me this issue. Sorry for not giving more specific at first;

Comment: @PhucTrinh Try using `SUM(t2.EST_VIEWS) OVER (ORDER BY t1.DATE)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, you want to have how many view a VIDEO_ID has had between  '2018-09-07' AND '2018-09-13', correct me if I am wrong. So if a VIDEO_ID was seen once on 2018-09-07 and twice on 2018-09-08 and not seen for the rest of the week, you want to have the sum which is 3.

You should use a [where](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#where) clause:

```
SELECT 
   VIDEO_ID,
   SUM(EST_VIEWS)
WHERE
   DATE(DATE)
BETWEEN 
   DATE('2018-09-07') AND DATE('2018-09-13')
GROUP BY
   VIDEO_ID
```