# Flat Big Query Rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please help me to resolve this task.  I have Google Big Query table like this:

```
| name | startDate  | endDate    |
| Bob  | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-01 |
| Nick | 2017-12-29 | 2017-12-31 |
```

and as a result I need to get something like this:

```
| name  | date       |
| Bob   | 2018-01-01 |
| Nick  | 2017-12-29 |
| Nick  | 2017-12-30 |
| Nick  | 2017-12-31 |
```

Is it possible?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just simply

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, date
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(startDate, endDate)) date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE as (
SELECT 'bob' name, date('2018-01-01') startDate, date('2018-01-01') endDate
UNION ALL SELECT 'Nick', date '2017-12-29' startDate, date('2017-12-31') endDate
),

CTE2 AS (
SELECT name, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(startDate, endDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date
FROM CTE
)

SELECT name, date
FROM CTE2,
UNNEST(date) as date
```

Answer (score 0):

You may make use of a calendar table here:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2017-12-29' AS date_val UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-30' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-31' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-01'
    -- and maybe other dates
)

SELECT
    t2.name,
    t1.date_val
FROM dates t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.date_val BETWEEN t2.startDate AND t2.endDate
ORDER BY
    t2.name,
    t1.date_val;
```

If your version of BigQuery does not support CTE, you may just inline the CTE as a subquery.  That is, replace `dates` with the body of the CTE itself.

In practice, you might want to generate a date series (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694040/how-to-generate-date-series-to-occupy-absent-dates-in-google-biqquery)), or possibly maintain a dedicated calendar table in your database.  The above just shows what the query itself might look like.