# Is there a way to expand a date range into rows in bigquery where you have historic data already present in the dataset?

Tags: sql

For eg.
Itemid start_date end_date
A.     2021-07-02.  2021-09-01
B.     2021-06-01.  2021-06-03

Output.
Itemid date
A.     2021-07-02
A.     2021-07-03 and so on and then
B.     2021-06-01
B.     2021-06-02

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags. Add the one back that you actually use!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view using this at bigquery and name it like v_date_dimension:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE('%F', d) as id,
  d AS full_date,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d) AS year,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM d) AS year_week,
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM d) AS year_day,
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d) AS fiscal_year,
  FORMAT_DATE('%Q', d) as fiscal_qtr,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d) AS month,
  FORMAT_DATE('%B', d) as month_name,
  FORMAT_DATE('%w', d) AS week_day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', d) AS day_name,
  (CASE WHEN FORMAT_DATE('%A', d) IN ('Sunday', 'Saturday') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS day_is_weekday,
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2014-01-01', '2050-01-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS d )
```

---

After that you can do a query like :

```
select * from v_date_dimension D
left join YOUR_TABLE tbl ON D.full_date between tbl.start_date and tbl.end_date
```

Comment: Thank you Ali. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187472/flat-big-query-rows This seemed to work for me as of now.