# Google Bigquery Legacy SQL - How to return a null or zero if no results returned?

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

Say I had the following table

```
month    region   revenue   
------  -------- ---------- 
 jan     north      100
 feb     north      150
 mar     north      250
```

How would I be able to query the above table to get the following results?:

```
month    region   revenue   
------  -------- ---------- 
 jan     north      100
 feb     north      150
 mar     north      250
 apr     north       0
 may     north       0
 jun     north       0
```

0's can be null's or vice versa. Essentially trying to add empty/null fields into my query (in this case the apr, may, jun rows). Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Legacy SQL, but please be advised  - it is strongly recommended bu BigQuery Team to migrate to [`BigQuery Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Below example should give you an idea

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  months.month_abr AS month_abr, 
  regions.region AS region, 
  COALESCE(revenues.revenue, 0) revenue
FROM months
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT region FROM revenues
) regions
LEFT JOIN revenues
ON months.month_abr = revenues.month_abr
AND regions.region = revenues.region
-- ORDER BY regions.region, months.month_number
```

where `revenues` is your original table with revenues data,  `month` is a table (or you can use subquery as in below example) with list of month

You can test / play with above using below example with dummy data from your question

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  months.month_abr AS month_abr, 
  regions.region AS region, 
  COALESCE(revenues.revenue, 0) revenue
FROM (
  SELECT month_number, month_abr FROM 
  (SELECT 1 month_number, 'jan' month_abr),
  (SELECT 2 month_number, 'feb' month_abr),
  (SELECT 3 month_number, 'mar' month_abr),
  (SELECT 4 month_number, 'apr' month_abr),
  (SELECT 5 month_number, 'may' month_abr),
  (SELECT 6 month_number, 'jun' month_abr)  
) AS months
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT region FROM (
    SELECT region FROM 
    (SELECT 'jan' month_abr, 'north' region, 100 revenue),
    (SELECT 'feb' month_abr, 'north' region, 150 revenue),
    (SELECT 'mar' month_abr, 'north' region, 250 revenue)
  ) GROUP BY region
) regions
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT month_abr, region, revenue FROM 
  (SELECT 'jan' month_abr, 'north' region, 100 revenue),
  (SELECT 'feb' month_abr, 'north' region, 150 revenue),
  (SELECT 'mar' month_abr, 'north' region, 250 revenue)
) AS revenues
ON months.month_abr = revenues.month_abr
AND regions.region = revenues.region
ORDER BY regions.region, months.month_number
```

with result as below

```sql
Row month_abr   region  revenue  
1   jan         north   100  
2   feb         north   150  
3   mar         north   250  
4   apr         north   0    
5   may         north   0    
6   jun         north   0
```

And finally - below is how same can look like for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH regions AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT region FROM revenues
), months AS (
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) month_number,
  LOWER(FORMAT_DATE('%b', month)) month_abr
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2010-12-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT month_abr, region, COALESCE(revenues.revenue, 0) revenue
FROM months
CROSS JOIN regions
LEFT JOIN revenues
USING(month_abr, region)
ORDER BY region, month_number
```

You can be test, play with this using dummy data from your questions

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH revenues AS (
  SELECT 'jan' month_abr, 'north' region, 100 revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT 'feb', 'north', 150 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'mar', 'north', 250 
), regions AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT region FROM revenues
), months AS (
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) month_number,
  LOWER(FORMAT_DATE('%b', month)) month_abr
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2010-12-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) month
)
SELECT month_abr, region, COALESCE(revenues.revenue, 0) revenue
FROM months
CROSS JOIN regions
LEFT JOIN revenues
USING(month_abr, region)
ORDER BY region, month_number
```

You should be able to apply above to your real use case

Comment: Thanks, used your second block of code and your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306016/populating-a-table-with-all-dates-in-a-given-range-in-google-bigquery to get what i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

One option - run a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN with the list of values you want to go through.

Let's start with a query missing the nulls/zeros:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT year, SUM(number) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
WHERE name='Felipe'
AND year>2014
GROUP BY year 
ORDER BY year
```

[image]

If we want to get 0s for the values before 2015:

```
SELECT b.year, IFNULL(c, 0) c
FROM (
  SELECT year, SUM(number) c
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
  WHERE name='Felipe'
  AND year>2014
  GROUP BY year 
) a
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT year FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2012, 2016)) year
) b
ON a.year=b.year
ORDER BY year
```

[image]

Also correlated subqueries can save the day:

```
SELECT year, (
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(number), 0) 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current` a
  WHERE name='Felipe'
  AND year>2014
  AND a.year=b.year
) c
FROM (SELECT year FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(2012, 2016)) year) b
ORDER BY year
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but unfortunately I'm using legacy sql

Comment: Yeah - I didn't notice the legacy in the title until I read Mikhaik's answer